# Tried to update to PHP 8.0 and everything that was installed composer, even php, fails to operate

Tags: php, homebrew

The error I would get would be something like this.
Basically all forms of `dyld: Library not loaded`

```sh
➜ php -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
[1]    62677 abort      php -v

~/Projects 
➜ valet use php@8.0

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
/Users/UserPerson/.composer/vendor/bin/valet: line 89: 63162 Abort trap: 6           php "$DIR/cli/valet.php" "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Super simple to fix, but I don't think this question had been answered in its complete form on Stack Overflow.

These 4 commands will get you your composer back!

```sh
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node icu4c
brew install node
brew link --overwrite node
brew upgrade

// Then install php 8 and a new laravel as a test!

composer create-project laravel/laravel funProject
```

Comment: Can you share more details? How should any node package be related to the given PHP problem which mentions any problem with an LDAP library?